# Module coming on all pages

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, module

I have a module for slideshow in landing page.

And I have some links in landing page.

When I click on those links.

The target page coming with module.

And I have not assigned the module on target page but still its coming.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to do this:

- Create a menu called: Hidden Menu
- Do not assign this menu to any menu module
- Create a menu element for each of the links you want to display in home page
  That way, they will have a diferent Itemid
- Sustitute your links for the new created in home page

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use Regular Labs (used to be NoNumbers) Advanced Module Manager so that you can assign the modules on the homepage to be "homepage" instead of assigned to the default menu item.  Doing this will prevent those modules from loading on menu-less pages so you don't have to create a ton of new hidden menu items.
https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedmodulemanager
https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedmodulemanager#assignment-options